# Scene Tab doesn't show anything beside canvas while Game Tab shows everything

Tags: unity, editors, unity-job-system

i've been building my script normally, but suddently after the last build, i don't see any GameObject Rendered in Scene Tab beside a canvas i have in another scene. I can see everything rendered in my Game Tab scene through camera.

If i move some object in Scene Tab, it moves in Game Tab too but no display of it at all. and i see the following warnings:

```
Internal: JobTempAlloc has allocations that are more than 4 frames old - this is not allowed and likely a leak

Internal: deleting an allocation that is older than its permitted lifetime of 4 frames (age = 6)

Internal: JobTempAlloc has allocations that are more than 4 frames old - this is not allowed and likely a leak

Internal: deleting an allocation that is older than its permitted lifetime of 4 frames (age = 12)
```

[image]

- I tried to reverse back the last build but no success
- I close and reopen the Scene Tab
- I Restarted my Computer too.
- I Observed that after the restart the project did load far slower ( like if it was the first time i open the project in the pc)
  Nothing of this did work

Edit: found out that the problem persists only within same project

[image: Inspector Image]
[image]

[image: shader error]

````
Compiling Vertex program
Platform defines: UNITY_ENABLE_REFLECTION_BUFFERS UNITY_USE_DITHER_MASK_FOR_ALPHABLENDED_SHADOWS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF1 UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION UNITY_SPECCUBE_BLENDING UNITY_ENABLE_DETAIL_NORMALMAP SHADER_API_DESKTOP UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA UNITY_LIGHT_PROBE_PROXY_VOLUME UNITY_LIGHTMAP_RGBM_ENCODING
Disabled keywords: UNITY_NO_DXT5nm UNITY_ENABLE_NATIVE_SHADOW_LOOKUPS UNITY_METAL_SHADOWS_USE_POINT_FILTERING UNITY_NO_SCREENSPACE_SHADOWS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF2 UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF3 UNITY_NO_FULL_STANDARD_SHADER UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER1 UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER2 UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER3 UNITY_HALF_PRECISION_FRAGMENT_SHADER_REGISTERS UNITY_LIGHTMAP_DLDR_ENCODING UNITY_LIGHTMAP_FULL_HDR UNITY_VIRTUAL_TEXTURING UNITY_PRETRANSFORM_TO_DISPLAY_ORIENTATION UNITY_ASTC_NORMALMAP_ENCODING SHADER_API_GLES30

Shader warning in 'Hidden/CameraMotionBlurDX11': integer modulus may be much slower, try using uints if possible. at line 153 (on d3d11)

Compiling Fragment program
Platform defines: UNITY_ENABLE_REFLECTION_BUFFERS UNITY_USE_DITHER_MASK_FOR_ALPHABLENDED_SHADOWS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF1 UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION UNITY_SPECCUBE_BLENDING UNITY_ENABLE_DETAIL_NORMALMAP SHADER_API_DESKTOP UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA UNITY_LIGHT_PROBE_PROXY_VOLUME UNITY_LIGHTMAP_RGBM_ENCODING
Disabled keywords: UNITY_NO_DXT5nm UNITY_ENABLE_NATIVE_SHADOW_LOOKUPS UNITY_METAL_SHADOWS_USE_POINT_FILTERING UNITY_NO_SCREENSPACE_SHADOWS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF2 UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF3 UNITY_NO_FULL_STANDARD_SHADER UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER1 UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER2 UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER3 UNITY_HALF_PRECISION_FRAGMENT_SHADER_REGISTERS UNITY_LIGHTMAP_DLDR_ENCODING UNITY_LIGHTMAP_FULL_HDR UNITY_VIRTUAL_TEXTURING UNITY_PRETRANSFORM_TO_DISPLAY_ORIENTATION UNITY_ASTC_NORMALMAP_ENCODING SHADER_API_GLES30

Shader warning in 'Hidden/SSAO': 's': loop control variable conflicts with a previous declaration in the outer scope; most recent declaration will be used at line 228 (on d3d11)

Compiling Vertex program
Platform defines: UNITY_ENABLE_REFLECTION_BUFFERS UNITY_USE_DITHER_MASK_FOR_ALPHABLENDED_SHADOWS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF1 UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION UNITY_SPECCUBE_BLENDING UNITY_ENABLE_DETAIL_NORMALMAP SHADER_API_DESKTOP UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA UNITY_LIGHT_PROBE_PROXY_VOLUME UNITY_LIGHTMAP_RGBM_ENCODING
Disabled keywords: UNITY_NO_DXT5nm UNITY_ENABLE_NATIVE_SHADOW_LOOKUPS UNITY_METAL_SHADOWS_USE_POINT_FILTERING UNITY_NO_SCREENSPACE_SHADOWS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF2 UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF3 UNITY_NO_FULL_STANDARD_SHADER UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER1 UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER2 UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER3 UNITY_HALF_PRECISION_FRAGMENT_SHADER_REGISTERS UNITY_LIGHTMAP_DLDR_ENCODING UNITY_LIGHTMAP_FULL_HDR UNITY_VIRTUAL_TEXTURING UNITY_PRETRANSFORM_TO_DISPLAY_ORIENTATION UNITY_ASTC_NORMALMAP_ENCODING SHADER_API_GLES30

Menu Cinemachine/Storyboard Global Mute can't be checked because it doesn't exist
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()
Cinemachine.Editor.CinemachineStoryboardMute/<>c:<.cctor>b__2_0 () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.cinemachine@2.6.4/Editor/Editors/CinemachineStoryboardEditor.cs:29)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallDelayFunctions ()

 ```
````

Comment: What do you see in the inspector for some of these objects? Does anything happen if you double-click on an object in the hierarchy or press F to zoom the scene view to fit the selection?

Comment: if i press zoom once or twice, i see same thing it's just the camera zoom in and out. but same thing in the image above as result . i should note also that gizmos aren't displayed too in the Scene Tab for some reason though activated

Comment: And the inspector?

Comment: Nothing changes in inspector. i added image to it as an Edit.

Comment: Update: I found out that Unity is stuck at baking shaders in this project. Some shader errors does appear too in the console. Image Above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to click on Layers found on the top in Unity and hit that slashed eye to unhide Default layer. I don't know how did the hide came to be triggered.

For all the warnings, all of them came from me trying to solve the problem by deleting ProjectSettings and Packages files since problem was on this Project only. Except the job warning which came from nowhere.
Anyway all the warnings where solved by closing/reopening the project.